# Globalモード(360 spherical video?)の動画を正距円筒図(equirectangular)に変換する方法

Tags: ubuntu

Kodak SP360で撮った動画 Globalモード(360 spherical video?)を正距円筒図(equirectangular)に変換する方法(ツール)を知りたいです。
Linux(Ubuntuを使っていますが)のコマンドラインで動くと最高です。ffmpegなど使えたらとも思っています。
どうしても難しければWin/Macも含めできる方法を教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 具体的なツールは思いつきませんが、フレームを静止画像に書きだした後、[極座標変換](http://authorunknown408.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-20.html)を行えば実現できそうな気がします。